# consulta sql que cuente cuantos dias de cada mes hay entre dos fechas agrupados por meses

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

acudo a ustedes porque he buscado y no he encontrado nada que me pueda ayudar con el problema que tengo. Debo mostrar en una consulta en SQL Server cuantos días de cada mes hay entre dos fechas pero agrupados por meses (tengo una fechaInicial y una fechaFinal), me explico con un ejemplo:

FechaInicial=2017-08-17

FechaFinal=2017-10-20

debería mostrar algo como

Agosto --> 15

Septiembre --> 30

Octubre --> 20

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma fácil es usando una tabla de fechas. Si no tienes una, puedes simularla de diferentes formas. En este caso, voy a usar la tabla `master.dbo.spt_values` (que tiene 2048 números diferentes, por lo que si usas un período de tiempo de más de esos días habría que modificar el código):

```
DECLARE @FechaInicial DATE = '20170817', @FechaFinal DATE = '20171020';


SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,number,@FechaInicial)) Mes,
        COUNT(*) Dias
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number,@FechaInicial) <= @FechaFinal 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,number,@FechaInicial)),
         DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,number,@FechaInicial))
ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,number,@FechaInicial))
;
```

[**Acá hay un demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=151f3c7a7e03f26ce358b433a7ac7fbc) de esto.

El resultado es:

```
╔═══════════╦══════╗
║    Mes    ║ Dias ║
╠═══════════╬══════╣
║ August    ║   15 ║
║ September ║   30 ║
║ October   ║   20 ║
╚═══════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Gracias me fue muy util

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Encontré un código que te puede servir, lamentablemente no tengo SQL Server a mano para probarlo, pero por lo que veo debería resultar:

```
DECLARE @s SMALLDATETIME, @e SMALLDATETIME;
SELECT  @s = '20120302',  @e = '20120605';

;WITH n(n) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @s, @e)+1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (ORDER BY [object_id])-1 FROM sys.all_objects
),
x(n,fd,ld) AS 
(
  SELECT n.n, DATEADD(MONTH, n.n, m.m), DATEADD(MONTH, n.n+1, m.m)
  FROM n, (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@s), @s)) AS m(m)
)
SELECT [Month] = DATENAME(MONTH, fd), [Days] = DATEDIFF(DAY, fd, ld) 
  - CASE WHEN @s > fd THEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, fd, @s)+1) ELSE 0 END
  - CASE WHEN @e < ld THEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, @e, ld)-1) ELSE 0 END
FROM x;
```

El código lo obtuve de aquí: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18626/how-to-get-the-total-days-per-month-between-two-dates

Hay otras respuestas ahí que te pueden servir también.

¡Saludos y éxito!

Comment: Tengan en cuenta que este algoritmo tiene un problema cuando el rango comienza el último día de un mes. Por ejemplo: `@s = '20120301' ` informará 0 días, creo que se le puede hacer un pequeño ajuste y funcionaría.